# Why *this* is not *this*?

Tags: javascript, scope, this

I just wrote this piece of code to represent this error that is killing me (Grrr!)

I wonder why when I get *error: method undefined* I have checked in Safari and this variable inside parserDidStart() method is not of type EpisodeController it is of type EpisodeFeedParser why is this?

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
var EpisodeFeedParser = function(url){
    this.url = url;
    this.didStartCallback = null;
};
EpisodeFeedParser.prototype.parse = function(doc){
    this.didStartCallback(this);
};

var EpisodeController = function(){
    this.episodes = new Array();
    this.parser = null; //lazy
};
EpisodeController.prototype.parserDidStart = function(parser){
    console.log("here *this* is not of type EpisodeController but it is EpisodeFeedParser Why?");
    this.testEpi(); //**********ERROR HERE!***********
};
EpisodeController.prototype.fetchEpisodes = function(urlString){
    if(urlString !== undefined){
        if(parser === undefined){
            var parser = new EpisodeFeedParser(urlString);
            parser.didStartCallback = this.parserDidStart;
            this.parser = parser;
        }
        this.parser.parse();
    }
};
EpisodeController.prototype.testEpi = function(){
console.log("it worked!");
};

function testEpisode(){
    var controller = new EpisodeController();
    controller.fetchEpisodes("myurl");
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<button type="button" onclick="testEpisode()">press me</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The best code is peaceful code.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

this is a frequently misunderstood aspect of Javascript. (and by "this", I mean `this`)

You can think of `this` as another parameter that gets invisibly passed in to your functions. So when you write a function like,

```
function add (a,b) {
   return a+b;
}
```

you're really writing

```
function add(this, a, b) {
    return a+b;
}
```

That much is probably obvious, what isn't obvious is exactly *what* gets passed in, and named as "this". The rules for that are as follows. There are four ways to invoke a function, and they each bind a different thing to `this`.

### classic function call

```
add(a,b);
```

in the classic function call, `this` is bound to the global object. That rule is now universally seen as a mistake, and will probably be set to null in future versions.

### constructor invocation

```
new add(a,b);
```

in the constructor invocation, `this` is set to a fresh new object whose internal (and inaccessible) prototype pointer is set to add.prototype

### method invocation

```
someobject.add(a,b);
```

in the method invocation, `this` gets set to someobject. it doesn't matter where you originally defined add, whether it was inside a constructor, part of a particular object's prototype, or whatever. If you invoke a function in this way, `this` is set to whatever object you called it on. This is the rule you are running afoul of.

### call/apply invocation

```
 add.call(someobject,a,b);
```

in the call/apply invocation, `this` is set to whatever you pass in to the now visible first parameter of the call method.

what happens in your code is this:

```
 this.parser.didStartCallback = this.parserDidStart;
```

while you wrote parserDidStart with the expectation that its `this` would be an EpisodeController when you method invoke it... what actually happens is you're now changing its `this` from the EpisodeController to this.parser. That's not happening in *that* particular line of code. The switch doesn't physically happen until here:

```
this.didStartCallback(this);
```

where `this` in this instance is the EpisodeParser, and by the time this code is run, you've asigned parserDidStart to be named didStartCallback. When you call didStartCallback here, with this code, you're essentially saying...

didStartCallback.call(this,this);

by saying this.didStartCallback() ,you're setting its `this` to.. well.. the `this` when you call it.

You should be aware of a function called bind, which is explained here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind

Bind creates a new function from an existing function, whose `this` is fixed (bound) to whatever object you explicitly pass in.

Comment: A really nice explanation! +1

Comment: Thank you so much! Indeed I was trying to bind rather than assign one function to another. Now I know why this breaks. I didn't know about bind() seems to be what I was trying to do. Breton, your explanation is just great! ;)

Answer (score 2):

`this` passed to `didStartCallback` in

```
EpisodeFeedParser.prototype.parse = function(doc){
    this.didStartCallback(this);
```

is of type `EpisodeFeedParser`

and in `EpisodeController.prototype.fetchEpisodes` you affect `EpisodeController.parserDidStart` to `parser.didStartCallback`:

```
parser.didStartCallback = this.parserDidStart;
```

so `this.didStartCallback(this);` is in fact `EpisodeController.parserDidStart(this)`

and we saw at the beginning that this last `this` was of type `EpisodeFeedParser`.

Q.E.D

Comment: Manji,  I don't understand why doing `parser.didStartCallback = this.parserDidStart` will make `this.didStartCallback(this):` to be in fact `EpisodeController.parserDidStart(this)` Is there a javascript rule or so I am missing?

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
var that = this;
parser.didStartCallback = function(parser) {
  that.parserDidStart(parser);
};
```

This creates a closure that passes in the correct scope to `parserDidStart`. Currently, when you call `this.parser.parse()`, it passes the `EpisodeFeedParser` as context, as that's where it's called from. It's one of the quirks of scope in JavaScript, and can be pretty frustrating.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that "didStartCallBack" is being called on (and in the context of) "this", at a point in execution when "this" refers to the EpisodeFeedParser. I have fixed it using .call(), though I'm not sure why you'd need to write code this roundabout, I'm sure there must be a reason.

Important change:

```
parse: function(episodeController){
  this.didStartCallback.call(episodeController, this);
}//parse
```

Full Code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    //An interesting context problem...
    //Why is it of type EpisodeFeedParser?

    // ---- EpisodeFeedParser
    var EpisodeFeedParser = function(url){
        this.url = url;
    };  
    EpisodeFeedParser.prototype = {
        url:null,
        didStartCallback:null,
        parse: function(episodeController){
            this.didStartCallback.call(episodeController, this);
        }//parse
    }//prototype


    // ---- EpisodeController
    var EpisodeController = function(){
        this.episodes = new Array();
        this.parser = null; //lazy
    };

    EpisodeController.prototype = { 
        parserDidStart: function(parser){
            console.log("here *this* is not of type EpisodeController but it is EpisodeFeedParser Why?");
            debugger;
            this.testEpi(); //**********ERROR HERE!***********
        },

        fetchEpisodes: function(urlString){
            if(urlString !== undefined){
                if(this.parser === null){
                    this.parser = new EpisodeFeedParser(urlString);
                    this.parser.didStartCallback = this.parserDidStart;
                }//if
                this.parser.parse(this);
            }//if
        },//fetchEpisodes

        testEpi: function(){
            console.log("it worked!");
        }
    }//EpisodeController.prototype


    // ---- Global Stuff
    function testEpisode(){
        var controller = new EpisodeController();
        controller.fetchEpisodes("myurl");
    }
</script>
</head>

<body>
<button type="button" onclick="testEpisode()">press me</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Oh, and this is a perfect simplification of the problem (Resig): http://ejohn.org/apps/learn/#25

Answer (score 0):

```
EpisodeFeedParser.prototype.parse = function(doc){
    this.didStartCallback(this);
};
```

I don't understand why you'd expect `this` to be anything other than an `EpisodeFeedParser`.