# Applying OOP with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop, jquery-events

I'm working with jQuery and trying to apply some basic Javascript OOP principles to a set of functions that control hover behavior. However, I can't figure out how to get the "this" keyword to refer to the instance of the object I'm creating. My sample code is:

```
var zoomin = new Object();

zoomin = function() {
       // Constructor goes here
};

zoomin.prototype = {
       hoverOn: function() {
          this.hoverReset();
          // More logic here using jQuery's $(this)...
       },
       hoverReset: function() {
          // Some logic here.
       }
       };

// Create new instance of zoomin and apply event handler to matching classes.
var my_zoomin = new zoomin();
$(".some_class").hover(my_zoomin.hoverOn, function() { return null; });
```

The problematic line in the above code is the call to `this.hoverReset()` inside the `hoverOn()` function. Since `this` now refers to element that was hovered on, it does not work as intended. I would basically like to call the function `hoverReset()` for that instance of the object (`my_zoomin)`.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Only assigning a function to a property of an object does not associated `this` inside the function with the object. It is the way how you call the function.

By calling

```
.hover(my_zoomin.hoverOn,...)
```

you are only passing the function. It will not "remember" to which object it belonged. What you can do is to pass an anonymous function and call `hoverOn` inside:

```
.hover(function(){ my_zoomin.hoverOn(); },...)
```

This will make the `this` inside `hoverOn` refer to `my_zoomin`. So the call to `this.hoverReset()` will work. However, inside `hoverOn`, you will **not** have a reference to the jQuery object created by the selector.

One solution would be to pass the selected elements as parameter:

```
var zoomin = function() {
   // Constructor goes here
};

zoomin.prototype = {
   hoverOn: function($ele) {
      this.hoverReset($ele);
      // More logic here using jQuery's $ele...
   },
   hoverReset: function($ele) {
      // Some logic here.
   }
};


var my_zoomin = new zoomin();
$(".some_class").hover(function() { 
    my_zoomin.hoverOn($(this));  // pass $(this) to the method
}, function() { 
    return null; 
});
```

---

As a next step, you could consider making a [*jQuery plugin*](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring).

Comment: Thanks for your excellent answer. It has really clarified things for me :-) I'll definitely look into making it a plugin.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can "bind" the event handler to the object ([see Mootools bind code](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Types/Function#Function%3abind) for example).
2. You can pass the object as a parameter in the anonymous function and use that instead of `this` in the event handler

As for 1, you add the `bind` method to `function`

```
bind: function(bind){
        var self = this,
            args = (arguments.length > 1) ? Array.slice(arguments, 1) : null;

        return function(){
            if (!args && !arguments.length) return self.call(bind);
            if (args && arguments.length) return self.apply(bind, args.concat(Array.from(arguments)));
            return self.apply(bind, args || arguments);
        };
    }
```

Not sure though how well it will interact with JQ stuff.

Answer (score 0):

please see my answers to these questions:

[where is my "this"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085674/where-is-my-this-using-objects-method-as-a-callback-function/1085715#1085715)

[why is "this" not *this*?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5639451/why-this-is-not-this/5692094#5692094)

`this` confusion comes up all the time.

when you pass a function in as a callback, it's invoked as a standalone function, so its "this" becomes the global object.

"bind" is a native part of ecmascript 5, and is part of the function prototype. If you go to the end of my second answer up there, you get a link to the mozilla website, which has a "compatibility" version of the bind function. Use use myfunction.bind(myobject), and it'll use the native function if it's available, or the JS function if it is not.