# jQuery breaking "this" in constructor?

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop

I'm working with jQuery and creating some OOP Javascript functionality. The object and its constructor has the following structure:

```
var zoomin = new Object();
zoomin = function() { // This is my constructor
    this.someFunction();
};

zoomin.prototype = {
    someFunction: function() {
        // More code here
    }
};
```

When I create an instance of zoomin (e.g. var my_zoom = new zoomin();), the call to this.someFunction() in the constructor does not work. It seems like jQuery is taking possession of "this" and this is why it is breaking.

I would really appreciate any help on how to get this to work properly.

Thanks!

Comment: It seems that you have another question with this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5852560/applying-oop-with-jquery.

Comment: Every time you use `new Object()`, God kills someone named Brendan Eich.

Comment: There's nothing related to jQuery in your code. Post a complete (but minimal) example including the jQuery code.

Comment: You can omit `var zoomin = new Object();` as you are immediately overwriting the value by assigning a function to `zoomin`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your class definition should be like this:

```
function zoomin() {    // This is my constructor
   this.someFunction();
};
```

For the member method definition, it should be:

```
zoomin.prototype.someFunction = function() {
     // More code here
};
```

or:

```
$.extend(zoomin.prototype, {
   someFunction : function() {
      // More code here
   }
});
```

Hope this helps. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

your code is pretty messed up. you're creating a new Object, then assigning function to the same variable. so the first statement is not necessary (and not a good practice), then assigning object (with some properties) to the prototype of the zoomin object, instead of adding a property (someFunction) to it.

try to define your constructor like this:

```
function zoomin(){
// this is your constructor
}
zoomin.prototype.someFunction = function(){
// this is your method.
}

var zm = new zoomin();
zm.someFunction();
```

Answer (score 1):

See the other answers as to cleaner ways to organize this. *This answer just tries to address the notion of "jQuerying breaking 'this' in constructor".*

**A function-object (e.g. `zoomin`) *must* be invoked with `new` to act as a Constructor** (constructors are just functions, there is nothing special without `new`). That is, if `zoomin` is used as a callback function in jQuery then `this` will be a particular (but arbitrary) object which is likely not a new object instance. This could give the illusion that jQuery breaks the constructor; however, it does not, because the constructor was not invoked with `new` and thus acts like a "normal function".

**If using `new fnObject` then `this` (inside the fnOjbect function) will *always* be a new "fnObject" instance.** There is *no way* for jQuery to change this, even if it tried really, really hard.

Also, the `zoomin = new Object` is 100% useless because the next line just assigns a new value (the constructor function-object) to `zoomin` :-)

Happy coding.